# Why is this value becoming NaN after a Pandas merge?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge two tables, but after the merge one record has a missing value despite it existing in the table being merged.

munro_ratings

|  | Mountain | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A' Bhuidheanach Bheag | 2.33 |
| 1 | A' Chailleach | 3.44 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 280 | Tom a' Chòinich | 3.40 |
| 281 | Tom na Gruagaich (Beinn Alligin) | 4.40 |

munro_merge

|  | Mountain | Ascents | Altitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A' Bhuidheanach Bheag | 5723 | 936 |
| 1 | A' Chailleach | 3269 | 997 |
| ... | ... ... ... |  |  |
| 280 | Tom a' Choinich | 3430 | 1112 |
| 281 | Tom na Gruagaich | (Beinn Alligin) | 5728 |

merge code

```
munro_mergeRating = pd.merge(left=munro_merge, right=munro_ratings, how='left', left_on='Mountain', right_on='Mountain')
```

merged table

|  | Mountain | Ascents | Altitude | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A' Bhuidheanach Bheag | 5723 | 936 | 2.33 |
| 1 | A' Chailleach | 3269 | 997 | 3.44 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 280 | Tom a' Choinich | 3430 | 1112 | NaN |
| 281 | Tom na Gruagaich (Beinn Alligin) | 5728 | 922 | 4.40 |

As you can see the rating for Tom a' Choinich becomes NaN after merging, and I'm not sure why. It is the only record this happens to. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in the first table the mountain name is 'Tom a' Chòinic' (the accent on o) but in the second table it is 'Tom a' Choinich' (no accent). Since the names are different, it see's it as different records. Try making them the same strings.